# Name box does not appear correctly in community moderator election page

Tags: bug, display

In the current [Community Moderator Election](https://english.stackexchange.com/election) the name box (the one showing the user name and the candidate score) does not show correctly in my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari in Mac OS X).

I tried this with incognito mode also, where there is no extensions running, so I think this is not an issue of my browser.

Screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of the page showing the bug]